# Create a Flask and React Full Stack Application

Tags: reactjs, flask, react-fullstack

How do I create a website with a React Front end and a Flask backend?

I have created websites using flask and templates, and I have made pages using react, and now I would like to combine them.

I have tried a few things and the only things that worked required going into react config files and were very complicated. And even then it was complicated to use fetch and I had to run npm run build every time I changed the react file.

This seems to me like something that would be done all of the time yet I can't find any simple resources to do this.

Is there something that I fundamentally don't understand regarding websites and I am going at this the wrong way?

Comment: Lots of ways to approach this depending on a variety of factors. Are you running locally or deploying to the web? Managed platform (GAE, Heroku) or bare-bones VM? Containers? The best answer will be a function of your use case.

Comment: Literally all I want is to build a simple flask app but instead of rendering templates, I want to render React pages, and I want the React to be able to use fetch("/API") to get info from the server, I haven't worked with all those complicated things you mentioned so I don't really need those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on a development workflow, as there are countless choices in how to deploy to a production environment.

Run your Flask app with `/api` as the root url prefix, either manually by prefixing all your route decorators or with the use of a Blueprint.

`py/app.py`

```py
@app.route('/api')
def index():
    return {'message':'hello'}
```

Add the Flask development server url to your `package.json` file

`js/package.json`

```
{
    ...,
    "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Fetch your data using a component

`js/Flask.js`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Flask extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { data: {}, status: null }
    }

    fetchData() {
        let status
        fetch('/api')
        .then((res) => {
            return {
                data: res.json(),
                status: status
            }
        })
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ ...data })
        }
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err)
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData()
    }

    render() {
        const { data, status } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Status: { status }</h3>
                <pre>
                    { JSON.stringify(data) }
                </pre>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Flask
```

Finally, include the component in your main `App`

`js/App.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import Flask from './Flask'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Flask />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Start your Flask server with your preferred method, either `flask run` or by executing your script directly, then start your JS development server with either `yarn` or `npm start`. You should see the response from your api route displayed at `http://localhost:8000`

As long as you are running your Flask server with `debug=True` and use `npm start` (*not* `npm run build`), any changes made with either the backend or frontend will be automatically detected and your app reloaded.